# c++ app can't receive consecutive messages from c# app

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

My problem is that when I do

```
TcpClient con = new TcpClient ("127.0.0.1", 5432);
            NetworkStream str = con.GetStream ();
Annoucement msg = new Annoucement ();
            msg.typ = Annoucement.msgType.NOWY_GRACZ;

            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix (str, msg, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix (str, msg, PrefixStyle.Base128);
```

and I try to receive with custom library that uses protocol buffers

```
Connection con = server.accept();

    Annoucement ann = con.receive();
    cout << ann.typ() << endl;

    ann = con.receive();
    cout << ann.typ() << endl;
```

I can read only the first one. The second is wrong because the field `typ` is set to 0 whereas it should be 3. I think that function receive do something wrong but don't know what.

```
  Annoucement Connection::receive() throw(EmptySocket) {
    CodedInputStream coded_input(raw_input);
    google::protobuf::uint32 n;
    coded_input.ReadVarint32(&n);
    char *b;
    int m;
    coded_input.GetDirectBufferPointer((const void**)&b, &m);
    Annoucement ann;
    ann.ParseFromArray(b, n);
    return ann;
  }
```

one variable is initialised in constructor

```
FileInputStream* raw_input;
 raw_input = new FileInputStream(s);  //s is socket in this example communication
```

How can I modify it so that I can read consecutive messages from the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream.html#CodedInputStream.GetDirectBufferPointer.details):

> Sets *data to point directly at the
>   unread part of the CodedInputStream's
>   underlying buffer, and *size to the
>   size of that buffer, but does not
>   advance the stream's current position.
>
> This will always either produce a
>   non-empty buffer or return false. If
>   the caller consumes any of this data,
>   it should then call Skip() to skip
>   over the consumed bytes. This may be
>   useful for implementing external fast
>   parsing routines for types of data not
>   covered by the CodedInputStream
>   interface.

I see these missing in your code:

1. Handling the case where both the announcements are already in the buffer on the first call.
2. Calling `coded_input.Skip()` (should cover #1 above if used right)
3. Error handling (including the case where there are no announcements already in the buffer at the call).

I'm guessing your problem is caused by #3 above, but I'm not sure until I see the `ParseFromArray` code.